# URL rewriting using similar MapRoutes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, url-routing, maproute

I have 2 similar maproute requests but I'm trying to target different routes.

Basically I'm creating a picture project using ASP.NET MVC.

What I want is to have the URL as:

**website.com/pictures/username**

and

**website.com/pictures/pictureid**

I'm using this as the map routes atm. Hoped that the different signatures would be enough to distinguish which action i would need.

The pictures controller has the action methods as
ActionResult Index (string username) { ... } 
ActionResult Index (long id) { ... }

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "UsersPicturesRoute",
    "Pictures/{username}",
    new { controller = "Pictures", action = "Index", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "SinglePictureRoute",
    "Pictures/{id}",
    new { controller = "Pictures", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Is there a way to have this desired outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your RegisterRoutes in below sequence then you will get your required output

```
routes.MapRoute(
          "SinglePictureRoute",
          "Pictures/{id}",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "abcd", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
          new { id = @"\d+" } // Parameter constraints
      );

routes.MapRoute(
         "UsersPicturesRoute",
         "Pictures/{username}",
         new { controller = "Home", action = "abcTest", username = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );
```

Comment: This works but I'm curious as to why!? What's actually happening? What does this **new { id = @"\d" }** do and why does it matter if it's below or on top? Hopefully you could explain? Thanks

Comment: Please look at this link http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

Comment: If you not add integer request MapRoute above the string request Maproute at that time when you call integer request then it will execute string request MapRoute because integer request will understand as string request so MVC never execute your integer request.